# Adding checkbox overlay for addon

Tags: 3d-view

i'm working with stats show addon
[image]
[image]

But i really want to add checkbox for visibility here 
[image]

How to propetly get layout of this panel and add checkbox?

**Upd**

Solved by [AFWS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/66285/afws)

[Download final script](https://yadi.sk/d/khBijYvUu1h9ug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would prolly have to edit the overlays file to get it in that location. Pretty easy to add settings to overlays though.

```
import bpy

def draw_stats_overlay(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    win = context.window_manager

    layout.label(text="Show Stats")
    layout.prop(win, 'stats_toggle')


def register():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay.append(draw_stats_overlay)

    bpy.types.WindowManager.stats_toggle = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "Toggle Stats",
        default = False
      )

def unregister():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay.remove(draw_stats_overlay)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.stats_toggle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Edit:

You might could do something like this.

Remove just the guides settings.

```
import bpy


bpy.utils.unregister_class(bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay_guides)
```

[image]

Add the settings back with the new setting.

```
import bpy

def guides_with_new_settings(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    view = context.space_data
    scene = context.scene

    overlay = view.overlay
    shading = view.shading
    display_all = overlay.show_overlays

    col = layout.column()
    col.label(text="Guides")

    col = layout.column()
    col.active = display_all

    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()

    row = sub.row()
    row_el = row.column()
    row_el.prop(overlay, "show_ortho_grid", text="Grid")
    grid_active = (
        view.region_quadviews or
        (view.region_3d.is_orthographic_side_view and not view.region_3d.is_perspective)
    )
    row_el.active = grid_active
    row.prop(overlay, "show_floor", text="Floor")

    if overlay.show_floor or overlay.show_ortho_grid:
        sub = col.row(align=True)
        sub.active = (
            (overlay.show_floor and not view.region_3d.is_orthographic_side_view) or
            (overlay.show_ortho_grid and grid_active)
        )
        sub.prop(overlay, "grid_scale", text="Scale")
        sub = sub.row(align=True)
        sub.active = scene.unit_settings.system == 'NONE'
        sub.prop(overlay, "grid_subdivisions", text="Subdivisions")

    sub = split.column()
    row = sub.row()
    row.label(text="Axes")

    subrow = row.row(align=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_x", text="X", toggle=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_y", text="Y", toggle=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_z", text="Z", toggle=True)

    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_text", text="Text Info")
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_cursor", text="3D Cursor")

    if shading.type == 'MATERIAL':
        col.prop(overlay, "show_look_dev")

    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_annotation", text="Annotations")

    #Add my new setting here
    sub = split.column()        
    sub.prop(context.window_manager, "stats_toggle", text="Toggle Stats")


def register():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay.append(guides_with_new_settings)

    bpy.types.WindowManager.stats_toggle = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "Toggle Stats",
        default = False
      )

def unregister():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay.remove(guides_with_new_settings)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.stats_toggle


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Addon example

````
bl_info = {
    "name": "Overlay Stats Test",
    "version": (0, 0, 2),
    "blender": (2, 82, 0),
    "location": "",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "3D View",
}

import bpy


#Guide settings with new setting added
def guides_with_new_settings(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    view = context.space_data
    scene = context.scene

    overlay = view.overlay
    shading = view.shading
    display_all = overlay.show_overlays

    col = layout.column()
    col.label(text="Guides")

    col = layout.column()
    col.active = display_all

    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()

    row = sub.row()
    row_el = row.column()
    row_el.prop(overlay, "show_ortho_grid", text="Grid")
    grid_active = (
        view.region_quadviews or
        (view.region_3d.is_orthographic_side_view and not view.region_3d.is_perspective)
    )
    row_el.active = grid_active
    row.prop(overlay, "show_floor", text="Floor")

    if overlay.show_floor or overlay.show_ortho_grid:
        sub = col.row(align=True)
        sub.active = (
            (overlay.show_floor and not view.region_3d.is_orthographic_side_view) or
            (overlay.show_ortho_grid and grid_active)
        )
        sub.prop(overlay, "grid_scale", text="Scale")
        sub = sub.row(align=True)
        sub.active = scene.unit_settings.system == 'NONE'
        sub.prop(overlay, "grid_subdivisions", text="Subdivisions")

    sub = split.column()
    row = sub.row()
    row.label(text="Axes")

    subrow = row.row(align=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_x", text="X", toggle=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_y", text="Y", toggle=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_z", text="Z", toggle=True)

    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_text", text="Text Info")
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_cursor", text="3D Cursor")

    if shading.type == 'MATERIAL':
        col.prop(overlay, "show_look_dev")


    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_annotation", text="Annotations")

    #Add my new setting here
    sub = split.column()        
    sub.prop(context.window_manager, "stats_toggle", text="Toggle Stats")


#Guide settings without new setting
def guides_without_new_settings(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    view = context.space_data
    scene = context.scene

    overlay = view.overlay
    shading = view.shading
    display_all = overlay.show_overlays

    col = layout.column()
    col.label(text="Guides")

    col = layout.column()
    col.active = display_all

    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()

    row = sub.row()
    row_el = row.column()
    row_el.prop(overlay, "show_ortho_grid", text="Grid")
    grid_active = (
        view.region_quadviews or
        (view.region_3d.is_orthographic_side_view and not view.region_3d.is_perspective)
    )
    row_el.active = grid_active
    row.prop(overlay, "show_floor", text="Floor")

    if overlay.show_floor or overlay.show_ortho_grid:
        sub = col.row(align=True)
        sub.active = (
            (overlay.show_floor and not view.region_3d.is_orthographic_side_view) or
            (overlay.show_ortho_grid and grid_active)
        )
        sub.prop(overlay, "grid_scale", text="Scale")
        sub = sub.row(align=True)
        sub.active = scene.unit_settings.system == 'NONE'
        sub.prop(overlay, "grid_subdivisions", text="Subdivisions")

    sub = split.column()
    row = sub.row()
    row.label(text="Axes")

    subrow = row.row(align=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_x", text="X", toggle=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_y", text="Y", toggle=True)
    subrow.prop(overlay, "show_axis_z", text="Z", toggle=True)

    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_text", text="Text Info")
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_cursor", text="3D Cursor")

    if shading.type == 'MATERIAL':
        col.prop(overlay, "show_look_dev")

    split = col.split()
    sub = split.column()
    sub.prop(overlay, "show_annotation", text="Annotations")


def register():
    #Check to make sure overlay guides panel is registered
    if hasattr(bpy.types, 'VIEW3D_PT_overlay_guides'):
        #Unregister if overlay guides is registered        
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay_guides)

    #Append guide settings with new setting when addon is registered    
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay.append(guides_with_new_settings)

    #Remove guide settings without new setting when addon is registered    
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay.remove(guides_without_new_settings)

    bpy.types.WindowManager.stats_toggle = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "Toggle Stats",
        default = False
      )

def unregister():
    #Remove guide settings with new setting when unregistering addon        
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay.remove(guides_with_new_settings)

    #Append guide settings without new setting when unregistering addon   
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_overlay.append(guides_without_new_settings)

    del bpy.types.WindowManager.stats_toggle


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Thank you! Just one question, is "append" function support to ability to add this prop in some defined place in this panel?

Comment: I edited my answer. You might could do it like I mentioned in my edit ,but append alone doesn't let you place in a certain location.

Comment: Thank you again! I didn't even know about overlay guides. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not the solution but i just add checking if general overlays is on 
[image]
[image]
[image]